# Mounted Samba permission problem

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, samba

I use Lubuntu as server machine and have few Lubuntu client machines.

On server Samba config file is configured that there is no need for passwords and everyone can write.

I added every user who will access from client machines to server users and groups.
Folder permissions are set that owner is nobody and group - **nogroup**. I added all users under this group.

When they access trough file manager PCManFM (smb://machine-ip/folder), mostly everything works fine.

But I need to be able to mount it.

On client machine I install cifs-utils then I edit /etc/fstab and add this line

```
//servername/sharename  /home/user-2/sharename  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

I mount it with user who is allowed to use sudo (user-1).

After that, /home/user-2/sharename i cant write with user-2

Owner is user-1 and group is nogroup, and by default on most of folders can write only owner and group.

I cant change owner and group even with root, also when I add user-2 to nogroup nothing happen, I can only change under permission view content, change content and access content to everyone.

Then I can write with user-2, but I cant then write to sub-folders. I need to repeat last step for every sub-folder.

When from another client machine user-3 add new folder, I need again then in machine with user-1 and user-2 manually set permissions to everyone can change content.

Maybe this text was not clear, in short:

1 server machine Lubuntu with Samba .

Few Lubutnu client machine, which need to mount this samba share and access to it. And there use folders, add new content...

Answer (score 0):

If you change the hunk that starts with guest to:

```
guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770
```

Does that solve it?